# Providing different routes/logic if on subdomain

Tags: angularjs, angular

What I'd like to do is if someone shits `domain.com`, hit a certain set of routes, and if you go to `site1.domain.com` or `site2.domain.com`, etc, hit a different set of routes. I considered making the subsites a different app, but a lot of components/logic will be shared, just certain parts will be tailored to the subsite.

I'm having difficulty figuring out where and how I should put the logic to figure out if I'm on a subdomain, and thus do an extra API call to get the subdomain's info (as far as I can tell, I just have to use the regular JS window.location object?), and once I have that info, how to modify routes accordingly.

For example, I'd like to have a system where the subdomains can have dynamically created menus, but with the routes being part of the `@NgModule` decorator, I'm not sure how I can do logic on the routes array prior to it being put in the injector (which is why I assume it's always shown as an array defined outside the class).

I suspect I'm just missing something fundamental about Angular, but I'm not sure what that may be.